# JavaFX applet communicating with server

Tags: web-services, client-server, javafx

I want to write some page with JavaFX applet. I want content on the applet to be dependent on user logged in.

I know I can call web services from JFX, but then what about login and session? Besides I think there might exist some better solutions for such communication than calling from applet a web service sitting on the machine applet comes from.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you say what is on your server side? a servlet?
I think there is nothing special about javafx. its just normal applet-server communication. you can call the needed java code to do the communication from your javafx

Comment: I don't know what's on server side yet. This project is not even started yet :) Probably I'll put servlets there. I know it is normal applet-server, but javaFX has some additional support for web services, I just thought that maybe it has also something for this applet-server communication.

Comment: Ok, I only know about the web service support too. In my project I needed communication with an application server, and I did it with normal java jndi lookup. Can't help you further, but I'm interested to see how this is done best - I'll keep an eye on your question

Answer (score 1):

You can build a servlet which returns the name of the logged in user.

Then in javafx you can use the class javafx.io.http.HttpRequest to call the servlet and read out the username. (The API also has some [examples](http://java.sun.com/javafx/1.2/docs/api/javafx.io.http/javafx.io.http.HttpRequest.html) of how to use the HttpRequest)

The following javafx code prints out the return string of a Servlet:

```
var response: String;

def myRequest: HttpRequest = HttpRequest {

location: "http://localhost:8080/demo/foo.do";

method: HttpRequest.GET;

onInput: function(is: java.io.InputStream) {
    var buff: StringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        var reader: BufferedReader

            = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        var data: String;

        while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {

          buff.append(data);

        }

        response = buff.toString();

        reader.close();
        println(response);
}
};

myRequest.start();
```

EDIT: You should also take a look at this article: http://blogs.oracle.com/warren/entry/authenticating_a_javafx_application_using which shows how to access the html document and cookies from within the applet which resides on the document. That should be a very interesting approach for authentication.

Comment: This is something I was missing, if only such HttpRequest shares session with "normal", browser request. I assume it does. So, does it?

Comment: hmm. Actually I just tried and they don't seem do share the same session. At least the session of the fx httprequest was empty. But I'm not that much into servlets. Maybe there is some way to store the username on serverside to return it to fx later.

But I also found another very interesting article I just added to the answer...